# li content styling on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I want to update the styling for li content on hover. but only the color is getting applied on hover and the content is not getting updated. any advice please

```
    li{
        &:hover{
          content: ' ★ ';
          color: red;
        }
      }
      li::before {
        content: ' ☆ '; 

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you try this?

```
li {
    &::before {
        content: ' ☆ '; 
    }
    &:hover {
        &::before {
            content: ' ★ ';
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Check on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0yx41vw/)

Answer (score 1):

```
li {
  &:before {
      content: '☆'; 
  }
  &:hover {
      &:before {
          content: '★';
          color: red;
      }
  }
}
```